# poner color a una columna especifica con DataTable desde JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap, codeigniter

Quiero poner color a una columna DataTable especifica desde javascript. los datos que se muestra en la tabla son obtenidos desde la DB.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta parte de código es el lado view

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="Tablexample" class="table mb-0 table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="btn-info">
                    <th></th>                                         
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Clientes</th>                       
                    <th>Moneda</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th class="bg-danger">Estado</th>
                    <th>Cobro</th>
                    <th>Saldo</th>                       
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

              </table>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usted puede utilizar la pseudo-clase :nth-child() de CSS y especificar el número del elemento que desea modificar, un ejemplo más claro sería de la siguiente manera en su hoja de estilo

```css
table th:nth-child(6),
table td:nth-child(6) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="Tablexample" class="table mb-0 table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="btn-info">
                    <th></th>                                         
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Clientes</th>                       
                    <th>Moneda</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Cobro</th>
                    <th>Saldo</th>                       
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>                                         
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>-</td>                       
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>Estado</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>-</td>                       
                    <td>-</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

            </div>    
            
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#Tablexample").DataTable();
</script>
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero cuando pongo el estilo mencionado solo me cambia el color de cabecera, quiero que de color a toda la columna como en la imagen señale.

Comment: He modificado el ejemplo, puede aplicar la pseudo-clase para los td igualmente, saludos